# how to pull data using xpath from script?

Tags: xpath, scrapy, command-line-interface

Just started learning scraping and for my test project i'm trying to retreive the quantity of a certain project in scrapy shell by using

```
response.xpath('//script[contains("quantity")]/text()').extract()
```

This doesn't work.
help me understand what should be the right covention to retreive data from such attributes like quantity, category_path & etc

```
<script>
        window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
        dataLayer.push({"event":"datalayer-initialized","region":"India","account_type":"ecom","customer":{"id":""},"page_type":"Product","product":{"ffr":"csddfas","name":"tote bag by singh","materials":"100% polyester","specs":"Dimensions: 18.5\" x 6.75\"; 24L","color":null,"size":null,"upc":null,"new":false,"brand":null,"season":"HOLIDAY 2017","on_sale":false,"quantity":"158","original_price":100,"price":100,"category_path":
        ["Mens","Accessories","Backpacks \/ Bags"],"created":"2016-09-07","modified":"2018-02-12",
        "colors":["BLACK"],"sizes":["S","M","L","XS","XL","XXL"]}});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scrapy selectors have [built-in](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#using-selectors-with-regular-expressions) support for regular expressions and it can help you on this case:

```
response.xpath('//script[contains(text(),"quantity")]/text()').re(r'"quantity":"(\d+)"')
```

*(you need to update your xpath to collect script content since your script not good enough)*

**Another Way:** You also can use regular expressions to collect the json content on script, parse them to json obj and work with it as easier!

Comment: thanks bud. i can use this code to extract any data from multiple attributes or just this one #quantity?

Comment: can you also tell me the regex for getting sizes?

Comment: you can replace my `.re(r'"quantity":"(\d+)"')` by your pattern! (e.g. replace `quantity` by `size`, ... as I think)

pls refer to https://www.regular-expressions.info/ base on what you want!

Answer (score 0):

You are using `css` method and giving it an `Xpath`

Try

```
response.xpath('//script[contains(text(),'quantity')]').extract()
```

or

```
response.css('script::contains(quantity)').extract()
```

And you will need a Regex to extract that JSON string

```
re.findall(r'(?<=dataLayer\.push\().*(?=\)\;)', your_script_tag_data, re.DOTALL)
```

Comment: sir, i was using xpath only, that was a typo now updated the question and using your xpath command it still returns the complete datalayer script.

Comment: datalayer script? please post your output in your question

Comment: sir, Complete Script is returned that is mentioned in the question.

Comment: @anshumananand you will need to use regex, please see my updated answer

Comment: ok, i know very less about regex so can you give a working code patch where i can pick certain data from this json string.

Comment: I already gave you working regex. Just parse that json and extract quantity

Answer (score 0):

```
javascript = response.xpath('//script[contains("quantity")]/text()').extract_first()
json_string = re.search( r'dataLayer\.push\((.+?)\);', javascript, re.DOTALL ).group(1)

data = json.loads(json_string)
print( "Quantity: {0}".format(data["product"]["quantity"]) )
```

Comment: the first command gives error of invalid no of arguments in //script[contains("quantity")]/text().

Answer (score -1):

In my experience, have no way to get quantity, category_path & etc by only Xpath, because they're in Json format. Xpath can get information in XML data.

I assume that you've already have xml data, use 
`python
data = yourXML.xpath('//script//text()')`

Now data is a string that contain all information. Then, you need to get string in dataLayer.push and convert it to Json format. With Json, it' easy to get your information.